# Where to set external DNS in DNSMASQ?

Tags: ubuntu-12.10, dnsmasq

I am getting "Query refused" from my network when I use `nslookup google.com`.

The DNS Server is 192.168.1.2 who runs dnsmasq.

It was working yesterday.

How can I solve it? I bet it's something about external DNS.

I need to add Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 so dnsmasq relays the request to those for external sites.

I read that I had to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` but that file says `Do not edit this file by hand, your changes will be overwritten`, so where can I add these servers to `dnsmasq`'s config file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `server` option:

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Search for "upstream" in [dnsmasq(8)](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html).

Comment: Thanks, where do I set it so it's added automatically each time the service starts? I mean, I see it's a `switch` to start dnsmasq in command line, so I would have to run manually. Thanks

Comment: Never mind I found `CONFIG FILE` in the manual and it says how to do it.